# Null Pointer Exception in button function

Tags: java, android, xml

```
Button btnEditor;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnEditor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditor);

    //some code

    btnEditor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        }
    });
}
```

`btnEditor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` gives me a **Null Pointer Exception**.
btnEditor is earlier connecter to XML Button by:
`btnEditor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditor);`

In my main.xml file:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEditor"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Editor"
        android:textSize="48dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal" android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
```

Seriously, I have no idea what to do...

**RESOLVED**

I forgot that I had two `main.xml` files:

- /res/layout
- /res/layout-large

One of them (in large dir) didn't contain a Button inside, so I got an error while running application on device using large layout.

Comment: what is the result of `(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditor);`. Is it null?

Comment: Where is the line `btnEditor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditor);` located? Can you post more code?

Comment: @Szymon I edited main post to show how it is located.

Comment: Do you have any other `@+id/btnEditor` in your xml?

Comment: No, I don't. It's the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you haven't called `setContentView()` with the `layout` that this `Button` is in or else you haven't called `setContentView()` *before* this line

```
btnEditor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditor);
```

either of these situations would give a `NPE` at that line and would be the only reason for it. If you think you are then please post how you are doing this.

Comment: I have called `setContentView()` to _main.xml_ where my button is. I edited first post to show it.

Comment: Try cleaning your project ("Project --> Clean...") and see if this line returns `null` `btnEditor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditor);`

Comment: Project cleaned:
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.piotr.mygame.Main.onCreate(Main.java:54)`
54 is `btnEditor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint there to see if `btnEditor` is `null`? It must be and the only reason is that this `Button` is not actually in the xml in `setContentView()`, you call `setContentView()` again before setting the `listener`, or you re-define the `Button`.

Comment: I set a breakpoint after this line and it's how you say: btnEditor is null.

Comment: Then the `Button` you posted must not be in `main.xml`

Comment: I was about to say that I DO have this button in my `main.xml` file and it would be true. **BUT** I forgot that I have two `main.xml`s files. One in _res/layour/_, another one in _res/layour-large_. But the second one didn't have a Button inside. So while I tried my application on device that used a large layout I got an error.

Basically, you were right :)

Answer (score 0):

try to do next:

1. btn.setOnclickListener(this);
2. Your class name implemented OnclickListener
3. Add Method OnClick
4. @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.R.id.btnEditor:
    your code
    break;
    }}

Comment: This does nothing to address the issue at hand

Answer (score 0):

write this as global variable

```
Button btnEditor ;
```

in your on create() write

```
btnEditor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditor);
btnEditor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: That's exactly how I'm doing it. I forget to include in first post global variable, but I use it.